# Can any Android device be set to not auto power-off?

Tags: screen, power-on, battery-life

If I buy any no-name Android tablet from ebay etc, is there a chance it will not allow me to force it to stay on all the time?  In other words, is "never auto sleep" a universal feature of any android device?

If not, how can I tell?

Comment: Why do you want your tablet to be always on?

Comment: You probably mean the Screen? Because the Operating System never really shuts down on itself. It just stays in Stand-By.

Comment: @silent_cookie I think, if _does_ shuts itself down, if you battery charge goes below 2%! :] Which is most likely in case OP is trying to make the screen on all the time, as we all know, that screens consumes enormous (the most) portions of battery charge...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the free [StayAwake app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gmail.developer.runks.enji)

> Simple app to toggle a stay awake mode.
>
> enables stay awake,
>
> - always
> - if plugged in to AC/USB